# Can't execute MySQL stored procedure in JDBC getting nullpointer exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, nullpointerexception

im not sure where to go from here i have messed with my code and i still get a null pointer exception. leading me to believe that maybe my connection is messed up... anyway unsure any help would be cool.

```
package callassstatement;
    import java.sql.CallableStatement;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class CallAssStatement {
    private static Connection conn;


    public static void printOptions() {

    System.out.println("enter 1 to get employee");
    System.out.println("enter 2 to get department");
    System.out.println("enter 3 to exit program");

}

public static String getEmployeeMethod(String id) {
    String abc = null;
    try {

        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(" { call sp_GetEmployee(1)}");


        cs.setString(1, id);
        //register the OUT parameter before calling the stored procedure
         cs.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

        cs.execute();

        //read the OUT parameter now
        String employeeId = cs.getString(1);
        String lastName = cs.getString(2);
        String firstName = cs.getString(3);
        String departmentId = cs.getString(4);
        String startDate = cs.getString(5);



            abc = ("EmplyeeID: " + employeeId + " " + lastName + "," + firstName + "" + " in " 
                    + departmentId + " Department "+ ", StartDate:"+ startDate);
            return abc;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return abc;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CandDLoader.createConn();

    printOptions();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner id = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = s.nextLine();


    switch (input) {
        case "1":
            System.out.println("calling get employee");
            System.out.println(" Enter employeeID:");
            String ab = id.nextLine();
            getEmployeeMethod(ab);
            break;
        case "2":
            System.out.print("calling get department");
            break;
        case "3":
            System.out.print("exiting");
            System.exit(0);
        default:
            System.out.print("what are you trying to do");
            printOptions();




    }
    }
```

here is my connection class.

```
package callassstatement;

   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.SQLException;


   public class CandDLoader {


   public static Connection createConn(){
Connection conn = null;
try{

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/timeclock", "timeclockuser", "password_1234");
    }
    catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex){}


    return conn;
    }
    }
```

Comment: i couldnt get my main in that post for some reason....
im trying to create an app that will call my sp and functions.

here is my run time in main method.

    run:
enter 1 to get employee
enter 2 to get department
enter 3 to exit program
1
calling get employee
 Enter employeeID:
123456

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at callassstatement.CallAssStatement.getEmployeeMethod(CallAssStatement.java:40)
 at callassstatement.CallAssStatement.main(CallAssStatement.java:94)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)

        }

Comment: Can you check the port no in the database url. I guess its missing

Comment: You couldn't get the main in the question because that's too much code. You should cut things off of it to make it display *only* your problem, creating a [mcve]. The stack trace should be in the question, not in a comment, nor should any lengthy code be in the comments. And finally, never have an empty `catch` clause in your code.

Comment: now i am getting Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0) error. can someone point me to a link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `createConn()` you do `return conn`, however in `main()`, you say

```
CandDLoader.createConn();
```

Therefore doing nothing with the returned `conn` and essentially throwing it away.

Either change that line to this

```
conn = CandDLoader.createConn();
```

Or change

```
private static Connection conn;
```

to this

```
private static Connection conn = CandDLoader.createConn();
```

---

When you declare object fields without assignment, they are assigned as `null`.

For example

```
private static Connection conn;
```

Is the exact same as saying

```
private static Connection conn = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below line of your codebase

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/timeclock", "timeclockuser", "password_1234");
```

The url provided here does not contain the port no, it should be as below:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/timeclock", "timeclockuser", "password_1234");
```

Answer (score 0):

`private static Connection conn;` in your `CallAssStatement` class is always null, you create a connection in `CandDLoader.createConn();` but you do not actually assign it to your `conn` variable in `CallAssStatement`.

Comment: CandDLoader.createConn(); is in my main method... can u elaborate what you mean

Comment: Please change `private static Connection conn;` just below the `public class CallAssStatement ` to  `private static Connection conn = CandDLoader.createConn();` and see if it works.